# Feasible with Tkinter 'scrollbar'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a base program I was playing with this morning I wrote up a few years back.  It only had horizontal scrolling and zooming.  I managed to get it so I could scroll(one axis at a time) and zoom on both axis.  I'm wanting to create a program that will allow me to move around the screen in both x and y directions at the same time(like Google Earth where you can hold down the down and left key at the same time to move to lower left).  It would be nice to do it without having the scroll bars on the screen as well.  I don't want to have to go back and forth and click on the appropriate scroll bar to be able to scroll in that axis.  Currently to change which axis I'm scrolling in I have to click on the opposite axis.

I tried the program at [http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html#scrolling][1] but I already have the capability of doing that.  It doesn't allow me to scroll both directions simultaneously and if I want to change which direction I'm scrolling without having to click on the opposite axis.

Is there a way of doing what I'm trying to do with Tkinter or should I look elsewhere and if so, where?

Thanks.

edit:

With the code Bryan posted below I added in the following code to try to get it two work with the keyboard versus only the mouse.  I would like the be able to use the cursor keys to move the image around versus the mouse.  I have a nastily touch sensitive mouse on this computer, that has a mind of its own and as a result I would like to stick with the keyboard.  Plus, given the naturedness of this darn project I have to leave all option open or else I know I will regret it sometime before this entire project gets finished.

```
self.canvas.bind("<Left>", self.on_press)
self.canvas.bind("<Right>", self.on_press)
```

I also tried directing it to self.on_motion and neither one accepted the cursor keys.

Comment: The true mystery of the world is the visible, not the invisible -- Oscar Wilde.  (except for your code, which is still a mystery)

Comment: It's kinda hard to add code when you don't have the sligthest idea if what you are trying to accomplish is even possible...you don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. There's nothing preventing you from directly calling the canvas `xview` and `yview` methods with any arguments you want.

You first need to create bindings that tracks the clicking and the motion of the mouse. In the bound function you can compute the direction that the mouse moved, then use the results to call both the `xview` and `yview` methods of the widget at the same time.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="bisque", width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000))

        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_motion)

        # the following two values cause the canvas to scroll
        # one pixel at a time
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollincrement=1, yscrollincrement=1)

        # finally, draw something on the canvas so we can watch it move
        for i in range(1000):
            x = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
            y = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
            color = random.choice(("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "violet"))
            self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+20, y+20, fill=color)

    def on_press(self, event):
        self.last_x = event.x
        self.last_y = event.y

    def on_motion(self, event):
        delta_x = event.x - self.last_x
        delta_y = event.y - self.last_y
        self.last_x = event.x
        self.last_y = event.y

        self.canvas.xview_scroll(-delta_x, "units")
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-delta_y, "units")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it works great but as I edited in above. ..is it possible to do it with the keyboard only?  I think I know enough to know I need to leave the mouse alone for right now and just use the keyboard for moving the image around.

Comment: @confused: of course it's possible. You can do it with any input mechanism you want. You simply need to compute how much to move in each direction using any method you want. It's not a good idea to drastically edit your question, because it makes what was a perfectly valid, acceptable answer into only a partial answer.